# Trouble displaying code on screen

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement

This might sound like a simple thing for you programmers out there but i can't seem to figure it out. I'm making a program that converts Decimal Numbers into Roman Numerals. I've got the core code working but i can't seem to think how i can display the results on the screen. I would like it so that when the user types a number into a text box the result appears in another text box at the press of a button. Thanks for your time & help.

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
var romans = {
    M:  1000,
    CM: 900,
    D:  500,
    CD: 400,
    C:  100,
    XC: 90,
    L:  50,
    XL: 40,
    X:  10,
    IX: 9,
    V:  5,
    IV: 4,
    I:  1,
};

var result = '';

for (var key in romans) {
    if (num >= romans[key]) {
        result += key.repeat(Math.trunc(num / romans[key]));
        num -= romans[key] * Math.trunc(num / romans[key]);
    }
}

return result;

}
```

Comment: Where's your HTML? You'd use (perhaps) `document.getElementById()` to get references to your text boxes, and `.addEventListener()` to add a handler for the `input` or `change` events to run your existing JS when the user types in the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a div element and give it an id like "output", you can do something like this.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the trusty old `alert` function. Just do `alert(convertToRoman(10))`. Put this in a `<script>` tag or inside body onload attribute
2. For fancier more professional debugging, you can use `console.log`. Originating with an old Firefox addon called Firebug, it is now supported by *all* browsers. Simply type `console.log(convertToRoman(10));` The result will be printed out to console, to see it, right click your browser, and open inspect document and move to Console tab, or alternatively, Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the part where you attach the result to the html. See working code below as an example.

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
  var romans = {
      M:  1000,
      CM: 900,
      D:  500,
      CD: 400,
      C:  100,
      XC: 90,
      L:  50,
      XL: 40,
      X:  10,
      IX: 9,
      V:  5,
      IV: 4,
      I:  1,
  };

  var result = '';

  for (var key in romans) {
      if (num >= romans[key]) {
          result += key.repeat(Math.trunc(num / romans[key]));
          num -= romans[key] * Math.trunc(num / romans[key]);
      }
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
}

convertToRoman(12345);
```

```html
<div> my result <span id="output"></span></div>
```